# How to change the API route prefix from "new-api" to "api"?

Tags: api, routes, sylius

I'm / We are developing a Sylius based shop. The Sylius API routes are prefixed by `new-api`. I too a look into the `/config/packages/security.yaml` and found there setting for both, `api` and `new_api`. If I see it correctly, the Sylius core team started to introduce that with by commit: [f4d7b54da3aee2783e3520454e91b6f9cd2977e1](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/commit/f4d7b54da3aee2783e3520454e91b6f9cd2977e1).

But why? Why does Sylius come with such a strange route prefix? Well, it's something, I really would like to know / understand. But currently I want to remove this route prefix and use `/api` instead. So I can just kind of replace `new_api` and `new-api` everywhere, but I worry about unexpected side effects. (It's actually why I want to know / understand the sense behind this "new-api".)

**How to remove / replace the `/new-api` API route prefix a proper way and use `/api` instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/new-api` prefix was replaced with `/api/v2` in Sylius 1.9.
The thought process behind this decision is described in https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/adr/2021_02_05_unified_api_prefix.md.

See the the upgrade instructions in https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/UPGRADE-1.9.md.